# Check free time beetween times and dates with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming that I have a table like this:

```
+----+----------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
| id | time_needed    | date_start | date_stop  | hour_start| hour_stop |
+----+----------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
|  1 |             30 | 2018-08-06 | 2018-08-06 | 08:00:00  | 08:30:00 |
|  2 |             96 | 2018-08-06 | 2018-08-06 | 10:45:00  | 14:21:00 |
|  3 |             20 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL      | NULL     |
|  4 |             56 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL      | NULL     |
+----+----------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

I know when I'll execute the operations 1 and 2, But instead for the 3 and 4 I just know the the time spent to execute the operations (20 and 56 minutes)
How can I check with mysql when I can execute the operation 3? I mean, is there a possibility to check when I have free time and for how long?
Looking at the table I can say that I have free time from the 08:31 to 10:44, but there is a way to check it with mysql?

---

EDIT

I would like to see the time free, beetween 8 am and 18 pm.

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: @Strawberry I would like to see the time free, beetween 8 am and 18 pm

Comment: Datediff function?

Comment: Or if this is a production scheduling problem, try the [earliest due date rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-machine_scheduling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are demanding is not (all alone) a task of mysql. mysql can give you the DATA according to your query - but your programming language should add the logic of scheduling entries, whenever possible.

At first i would start with the following database changes:

- Combine the date / hour columns into a datetime column.
- remove the end_date / end_hour - you always can calcluate this with `date_start + time_needed`

So, you end up with a datatable like this:

```
+----+----------------+---------------------+
| id | time_needed    | date_start          |
+----+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |             30 | 2018-08-06 08:00:00 |
|  2 |             96 | 2018-08-06 14:21:00 | 
+----+----------------+---------------------+
```

Now, all you need to do is: Join the table with itself, and make sure everything is calculated as it should be:

```
-- new Task takes 25 Minutes.
SELECT DISTINCT L.* FROM time_table L LEFT JOIN time_table R 
  -- compare with every later schedule
  on L.date_start < R.date_start 
WHERE
  -- use only rows that have enough time for the task that should be scheduled
  (date_add(L.date_start, INTERVAL L.time_needed + 25 MINUTE ) < R.date_start

  -- and only in the future
  and date_add(L.date_start, INTERVAL L.time_needed MINUTE) > NOW()

  -- due to the join, it might happen that we ignore entries in between. 
  -- make sure, there is no other task in the calculated timespan!
  and not exists 
   (SELECT id FROM time_table x WHERE 
      x.date_start > L.date_start AND 
      x.date_Start < date_add(L.date_start, INTERVAL L.time_needed + 25 MINUTE) )
  )


  -- and ofc. the last row in the schedule. 
  OR isnull (R.date_start);
```

This returns both datarows, as 25 minutes can be scheduled right after every other task. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02020d8/1

`14:21 - 08:00 is 6:21`, and 30 minutes are "booked". So the gap is 5:51 - so a `350` Minute Task should fit after `08:00` - a `351` Minute Task not:

350 minutes to be scheduled: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02020d8/2

351 minutes to be scheduled: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02020d8/3

All you got to do afterwards:

Take the smalles id, and insert your schedule right after it. Remember, `date_start` will be `prior_date_start + prior_time_needed`.

---

See this example as well: Scheduling a 20 minute Task would have 3 options with the example data (Added 2 columns for your convenience):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02020d8/8

Comment: Updated query to respect "the future" and avoid wrong associations with records that are multiple steps in the future.

Comment: You appear to  be missing a reference to the limiting parameters mentioned in the comments (8 and 18)

Comment: @Strawberry right, didn't see that comment. But shouldn't be a big deal to validate the returned timeslots for that constraint.